# Cannot upload picture in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, image-uploading

I have this basic form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::route('post-account-changeProfilePic'), 'files' => true, ))}}
{{ Form::file('photo') }}
<br />
{{ Form::submit('Regístrarme', array("class" => "button expand round")) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My Route is inside of 2 groups: `before=>Auth` and `before=>csrf`

```
Route::post('/accont/changeProfilePic', array(
    'as'    => 'post-account-changeProfilePic',
    'uses'  =>  'CallCenterController@postChangeProfilePic'
));
```

In my controller, I just dump my variable to see what I got:

```
public function postChangeProfilePic(){
    $input = Input::all();
    var_dump($input);
}
```

These are the errors I am getting:

1- Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException.

This because of the csrf filter, but since I am using blade, the token is actually there. Also, if I remove the name attribute from the file input, this error will not be displayed.

So far, I decided to place the route outside of the csrf filter until I understand what is going on.

2- After placing the route out of the csrf filter, and try to display all the inputs, I get a `null` array.

I decided to add a new text field and if I don't select a photo/pic and only send the form like that, it'll dump on screen all the inputs, but of course, the file is empty/null.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your form try changing this to 
array('before' => 'csrf'), function()

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::route('post-account-changeProfilePic'), 'before' => 'csrf'), 'files' => true, ))}}
```

The csrf token should be there by default since you are doing a POST request, so not sure where there is an issue there.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#csrf-protection

for the input try

```
public function postChangeProfilePic(){

    if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {
        $input= Input::file('photo');
        var_dump($input);
    }
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris.
The issue still remain. 
I have several routes inside of a group like:
    Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function(){ 
        //Routes here...
    });

And yes, the token is placed in the form by the framework.

The post array keeps "posting" as null... so dunno what to do

Comment: Okay, could you add another form input field for me. Just a text input and confirm that nothing is being posted from that input as well?

Comment: Indeed I did.
I added a text field to the form, and when I post it, the array displays all fields (token + textfield + file), but only if the file input is empty. If the file input is not empty, it does post "null".

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think it could be this

change

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::route('post-account-changeProfilePic'),
                        'files' => true, ))}}
```

to

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'post-account-changeProfilePic',
                        'files' => true )) }}
```

I don't think you need the ',' at the end of the true either.